# When does the sensitivity of tangent galvanometer approaches a max value?

Tags: instrument

[image]

**The image shows the approach of a few saying that the sensitivity is maximum if the deflection approaches zero. The white portion is a snap of a reference book which says the sensitivity is maximum if the deflection approaches $45^\circ$. Which is right? Kindly point out the mistake.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discrepancy arises because two different definitions are being used. Your book is defining sensitivity as change in deflection per unit *fractional* change in current. You are defining it as change in deflection per unit change in current.

I've never come across the first of these. That's not to say that it's outright wrong, but the reader would always have to be told that 'sensitivity' was being used in this sense. I think that most of us would use the second definition and say that the sensitivity is greatest for small currents, when $\theta \approx 0.$